# Earned Announcer badge - Dont understand how

Tags: support, badges

I recently received a notification that I had earned an Announcer badge

[image]

But why? I understand the badge I earned on April 25 but I don't remember answering the question [Webcam doesn't work in browser…?](https://askubuntu.com/q/191166/107450) and I don't see an answer from me or even a comment there now.

This is not a problem but I am intrigued to understand how I've earned this badge.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shared a link to an answer in that question on [Launchpad Answers.](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+question/228882)

Comment: Thanks that clears it up.  I had assumed that this badge was for links on a question or answer that people follow.  Not links from other sites to questions here.

Comment: Ah yeah. The badge is for directing traffic to the site.

Comment: Oh wow, so moderators can find out what the link is =D? I got the same badge a while ago too and was wondering the same thing. I don't even remember posting a link to AskUbuntu anywhere other than AskUbuntu. Please please please, can you tell me what my referrer link is =)?

Comment: @Alaa Hah, no. I searched Google for `askubuntu.com/a/*/107450` and his post showed up. I tried looking for yours and I can't find any. :-(

Comment: @jokerdino haha, well that was one lucky shot mate. Anyways, I think AskUbuntu should show us a link of where we shared the link to the question next to the badge.

Comment: @Alaa It's a [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108738) with no response from the team.